# Retrofit2 JSON response body not parsed correctly

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2, okhttp

I'm having problems implementing a custom class as response JSON in Retrofit2.

The call succeeds and when I log the body (using HttpLoggingInterceptor) I can see the JSON is fetched correctly.

The only problem is that it is not parsed into the custom class I created.

Here is my ServiceGenerator:

```
public class ServiceGenerator
{
    //Base url for the API
    public static final String API_BASE_URL = "http://base.url";

    private static Retrofit.Builder GSONBuilder =
            new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create());

    public static <T> T createJSONService(Class<T> serviceClass)
    {
        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

        HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
        httpClient.addInterceptor(logging);

        Retrofit retrofit = GSONBuilder.client(httpClient.build()).build();
        return retrofit.create(serviceClass);
    }
}
```

Here is the ServiceInterface:

```
public interface ServiceInterface
{
    class UserResponse
    {
        public int id;
        public String email;
        public String created_at;

        @Override
        public String toString()
        {
            return "UserResponse{" +
                "id: " + id +
                ", email: " + email +
                ", created_at: " + created_at +
                "}";
        }
    }
    @GET("user/{userId}")
    Call<UserResponse> currentUser(@Path("userId") int userId);
}
```

And this is where I actually call it:

```
public void getUser(int userId)
{
    ServiceInterface clientCreate = ServiceGenerator.createJSONService(ServiceInterface.class);
    Call<ServiceInterface.UserResponse> callCreate = clientCreate.currentUser(userId);

    callCreate.enqueue(new Callback<ServiceInterface.UserResponse>()
    {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<ServiceInterface.UserResponse> call, Response<ServiceInterface.UserResponse> response)
        {
            ServiceInterface.UserResponse user = response.body();
            if (user == null)
            {
                System.out.println("error");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println(user.toString());  
                //This line gets printed, but the class is empty 
                //What it should show: UserResponse{id: 5, email: "test@email.com", created_at: "2016-03-02"}
                //What it actually shows: UserResponse{id: 0, email: null, created_at: null}
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ServiceInterface.UserResponse> call, Throwable t)
        {
            System.out.println("Fail: " + t.getMessage());
        }
    });
}
```

I feel like I did everything right, is there any explanation why the GsonConverter does not convert the response to my custom class (UserResponse)?

To make myself even more clear, here is the actual JSON response (using Postman):

```
{"id": 5, "email": "test@email.com", "created_at": "2016-03-02"}
```

Thanks in advance!

---

Edit 1:

For anyone interested.

I have just figured out that if I use a String as a return type it actually writes all the data to the String.

So that means the fault lies with the conversion. I think that somewhere along the way I made a mistake with the GSONBuilder.

Comment: does it print "error"? Can you print the status code of the request ?

Comment: It gives me 200, so the call actually succeeds. Also if check the Log from HttpLoggingInterceptor it shows me the JSON that I requested, the only problem is getting it inside of the custom class and/or retrieving the information from the Response.

Comment: Add `@SerializedName` it might be cause of field name.